# Как вывести кусок кода wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Wordpress с помощью плагина FacetWP и куска кода

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[facetwp facet="facet_name"]'); ?>
```

выводит фильтр. 
Есть плагин Advanced Custom Field, создает и выводит кастомные поля. (Вывод поля:

```
<?php the_sub_field('field_name'); ?>)
```

Как сделать так, чтобы в админке в кастомном поле задать имя, которое будет подставляться в такого вида код

```
 <?php echo do_shortcode('[facetwp facet="facet_name"]'); ?>
```

и формировать фильтр?
У меня выводится только название.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[facetwp facet="' . the_sub_field('field_name') . '"]'); ?>
```